# Need some help with python string / slicing operations

Tags: python, string, slice

This is a very newbie question and i will probably get downvoted for it, but i quite honestly couldn't find the answer after at least an hour googling. I learned how to slice strings based on "exact locations" where you have to know exactly where the word ends. But i did not find any article that explained how do it on "non static" strings that could change.

Also i do not want to use string.split() in this case as its a little overkill for what i need.

I basically have a string like this:

```
myString = "!save python Python is a high-level object oriented language created by Guido van Rossum."
# the format is !save [singleword] [definition]
```

i need to "slice" this string but i cant figure out a proper way to do it.

i need to save a to variable the title (python in this case) and the definition of this string. Somethig like:

```
title = myString[1]
definition = myString[everything after string[1]
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this when you have a dynamic string where you dont know where each word ends.

I would greatly appreciate some pointers on what functions/methods should i read on to archieve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why is split overkill?

```
verb, title, definition = myString.split (' ', 2)
```

Comment: Would this affect the third part of his string that has multiple spaces in it?

Comment: Nope, second parameter for split says the maximum number of times to split the string. After the first 2 the rest of the string is returned.

Comment: @mandroid The second parameter tells it how many splits to perform. In this case it will stop splitting after it hits the second occurrence of the delimiter. 

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

When in doubt, crack open a shell and give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you have spaces between your command, title, and definition you could:

```
wordList = myString.split()
cmd = wordList[0] # !save
title = wordList[1] # python
definition = ' '.join(wordList[2:])  # Python is a high-level object oriented language created by Guido van Rossum.
```

If you really would rather not use split you could use regular expressions:

```
import re
m = re.match('(/S+)/s*(/S+)/s*(.*)')
cmd = m.group(1)
title = m.group(2)
definition = m.group(3)
```

Comment: this is a great answer! thank you so much! i will definitely use some of your suggestions ! thanks!

Comment: Ah, you don't want to use a saw. Here is a chainsaw instead!

Comment: Note that myString.split() does normalizing of whitespace, so doing the join() again afterwards doesn't get you back to the original "definition".

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer (after PEP8ing):

```
verb, title, definition = my_string.split(' ', 2)
```

splits on a single space. It's likely a better choice to split on runs of whitespace, just in case there are tabs or multiple spaces on either side of the title:

```
verb, title, definition = my_string.split(None, 2)
```

Also consider normalising the whitespace in the definition:

```
definition = ' '.join(definition.split())
```

Comment: @mhawke: I think that normali[sz]e_whitespace() would be a good candidate for a str method ... the join/split caper is very inefficient, especially when no change is required; a built-in could just return a reference to the original string in that case. One annoying thing about join/split is that \xA0 aka &nbsp; is not considered whitespace in the (default) C-locale in Python 2.x.

Comment: Generally speaking I like your recommendations, but I took his specification literally:  

# the format is !save [singleword] [definition]

Comment: @jholloway: re "I took his specification  literally" ... your confession comes rather late. Have you truly repented?

Comment: @John Machin Not sure what you mean, but I'll repent for the PEP8 mistake in my solution if that makes you happy :)

Comment: @jholloway: I meant: Have you truly repented taking the OP's specification literally?

Comment: @John Machin I guess not. My answer solves the problem as stated without inferring additional requirements around whitespace.  I agree that your amendment to my solution solves additional edge cases w/o adding complexity, but what is there to 'repent' for?

Comment: @John Machin Of course it occurs to me now that maybe you're being tongue-in-cheek and I'm not reading it correctly, so apologies in advance if I'm just being dense.

Comment: @jholloway: You need to repent the dreadful sin of taking a specification literally. Users and OPs never have extra whitespace, never have many to many relationships, never have duplicate data, etc etc. Apology accepted :-)